# I Cannot Get Any Files to Sync or Share Under Windows

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows

I initially installed Ubuntu One under Linux, and it seems to work flawlessly.  When I put files into my Ubuntu One sync folder, the files are uploaded to the web interface.  But for some reason, when I installed the Windows version, nothing seems to work at all.  I have double and triple checked everything, and I must be overlooking something.  I re-installed the .NET framework, yet nothing I put in /My Documents/Ubuntu One ever uploads to the website, nor does it sync with my linux system at home.  Please help!  I have no idea what is wrong.  It should be a simple process as putting files in the sync folder, clicking "sync" folder, and whatever is in that folder should upload to the web interface.  What am I doing wrong?  What am I overlooking?  Please help.  I would really love to switch over from DropBox to this service, because the price is definitely right, but I cannot make that move if I cannot get it work.  If I, a slightly competent computer guy cannot get it to work, how am I going to convince the cavemen I work for to switch?  I mean, asking to install .NET framework outside of the actual installer program is a lot to ask as is... so hopefully someone can help me, thanks!

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Ubuntu One does not seem to work on my Windows 7. Disappointing.

Comment: Is this still a problem troy, as it's almost been a year and alot of kinks have been worked out?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).